# sas: unable to figure out INTCK function error

Tags: datetime, sas

I am trying to use INTCK in the following manner but get error. I am not sure what I am doing wrong. I would appreciate your help. Thanks.

```
PROC FORMAT;
PICTURE DTFMT LOW-HIGH='%0m/%0d/%Y'  (DATATYPE=DATETIME);
RUN;

data want;
dt_val1='17JUL2006:00:00:00.000'dt;
dt_val2='17AUG2012:00:00:00.000'dt;
format dt_val1 dt_val2 dt_val3 dtfmt.;
dt_val3=intck('MONTH',dt_val1,dt_val2);
put dt_val3;
run;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's important to understand the difference between date and datetime values in SAS. This has been covered frequently on this site and others. Here's the [official documentation](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrcon/65287/HTML/default/viewer.htm#p1wj0wt2ebe2a0n1lv4lem9hdc0v.htm) and an excerpt.

> SAS date value is a value that represents the number of days between
> January 1, 1960, and a specified date.
>
> SAS time value is a value
> representing the number of seconds since midnight of the current day.
> SAS time values are between 0 and 86400.
>
> SAS datetime value is a value
> representing the number of seconds between January 1, 1960, and an
> hour/minute/second within a specified date.

They cannot be used interchangably, but you can convert between them. It appears that you should be using date variables in this application. That would probably make things a bit easier for you.

Converting dates to datetimes is easy and datetime values to dates is even easier:

```
dateval = datepart(dtval);
```

That said, your `intck` function is probably throwing an error because 'MONTH' is a date interval and not a datetime interval. Using 'DTMONTH' would probably work. Please see this [link](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrcon/65287/HTML/default/viewer.htm#p0g056g35ez8son1sfavozh0lfb3.htm) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

You need to convert to a date , so you can either use:

```
data want;
dt_val1='17JUL2006:00:00:00.000'dt;
dt_val2='17AUG2012:00:00:00.000'dt;
d1 =input(substr(put(dt_val1,datetime.),1,7),date7.);
d2 =input(substr(put(dt_val2,datetime.),1,7),date7.);
months=intck('month',d1,d2);
run;
```

or

```
   data want;
dt_val1='17JUL2006:00:00:00.000'd;
dt_val2='17AUG2012:00:00:00.000'd;
months=intck('month',dt_val1,dt_val2);
run;
```

or even better using datepart as probackpacker suggested:

```
data want;
dt_val1='17JUL2006:00:00:00.000'dt;
dt_val2='17AUG2012:00:00:00.000'dt;
months=intck('month',datepart(dt_val1),datepart(dt_val2));
run;
```

Comment: The `substr` solution is a little crude. Why not just use `datepart`?